# No route results after calling network analyst service

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server, arcgis-flex-api, network-analyst

I have published a network analyst service and I'm trying to use it from the Flex API 3.1.
When I use the service in ArcMap or through the rest GUI in a browser, the service returns the right answer.
When I use the service from the Flex API 3.1, my object "routeResult" that contains the route returned by the server is null.
I get the error: "Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference." for the object routeResult.
Here is my application code:

```
<s:layout>
    <s:BasicLayout/>
</s:layout>

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import com.esri.ags.events.MapMouseEvent;
        import com.esri.ags.events.RouteEvent;
        import com.esri.ags.FeatureSet;
        import com.esri.ags.Graphic;
        import com.esri.ags.symbols.CompositeSymbol;
        import com.esri.ags.symbols.SimpleMarkerSymbol;
        import com.esri.ags.symbols.TextSymbol;
        import com.esri.ags.tasks.supportClasses.RouteResult;

        import mx.controls.Alert;
        import mx.rpc.events.FaultEvent;

        [Bindable]private var stops:FeatureSet = new FeatureSet([]);

        [Bindable]private var lastRoute:Graphic;            

        private function mapClickHandler(event:MapMouseEvent):void
        {
            var stopSymbol:CompositeSymbol = new CompositeSymbol();
            var circleSym:SimpleMarkerSymbol = new SimpleMarkerSymbol(SimpleMarkerSymbol.STYLE_CIRCLE, 20, 0x000099);
            var textSym:TextSymbol = new TextSymbol(String(stops.features.length + 1));
            textSym.textFormat = new TextFormat("Verdana", null, null, true);
            textSym.color = 0xFFFFFF;
            stopSymbol.symbols = [ circleSym, textSym ];

                            var stop:Graphic = new Graphic(event.mapPoint, stopSymbol);
            inputsLayer.add(stop);
            stops.features.push(stop);

            if (stops.features.length > 1)
            {
                routeTask.solve(routeParams);
            }
        }

        private function solveCompleteHandler(event:RouteEvent):void
        {
            var routeResult:RouteResult = event.routeSolveResult.routeResults[0];
            lastRoute = routeResult.route;
            lastRoute.toolTip = routeResult.routeName;
            if (routeResult.route.attributes.Total_Time)
            {
                lastRoute.toolTip += " in " + Math.round(Number(routeResult.route.attributes.Total_Time)) + " minutes.";
            }
        }

        private function faultHandler(event:FaultEvent):void
        {
            Alert.show(event.fault.faultString + "\n\n" + event.fault.faultDetail, "Routing Error " + event.fault.faultCode);
            // Supprimer le dernier stop ou les deux s'il n'y en a pas plus.
            if (stops.features.length <= 2)
            {
                inputsLayer.clear();
                stops = new FeatureSet([]);
            }
            else
            {
                inputsLayer.remove(stops.features.pop());
            }
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>    

<fx:Declarations>       
    <esri:MapPoint id="mapPoint" x="655672" y="6861079"/>

    <esri:RouteTask id="routeTask" concurrency="last" fault="faultHandler(event)"
                    requestTimeout="30" showBusyCursor="true"
                    solveComplete="solveCompleteHandler(event)"
                    url="http://serverIP:8399/arcgis/rest/services/na_service/MapServer/Route"/>

    <esri:RouteParameters id="routeParams" stops="{stops}" returnDirections="false"/>

    <esri:SimpleLineSymbol id="routeSymbol" width="5" alpha="0.6" color="0x000099"/>
</fx:Declarations>

<s:BorderContainer id="applicationHolder" width="100%" height="100%">


    <s:layout>
        <s:VerticalLayout/>
    </s:layout>

    <s:SkinnableContainer id="headerBar" width="100%" height="50" backgroundColor="0xcccccc">
        <s:layout>
            <s:HorizontalLayout verticalAlign="middle"/>
        </s:layout>

        <mx:Text id="titleText" fontSize="25" fontWeight="bold"
                 text="My application"/>
        <mx:Spacer width="75"/>         

    </s:SkinnableContainer>

    <esri:Map id="mainMap" width="100%" height="100%" center="{mapPoint}"
              crosshairVisible="{crosshairsCheck.selected}" level="16"
              mapClick="mapClickHandler(event)" panArrowsVisible="{panArrowsCheck.selected}">
        <esri:ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer url="http://serverIP:8399/arcgis/rest/services/myMapService/MapServer"/>

        <esri:GraphicsLayer graphicProvider="{lastRoute}" symbol="{routeSymbol}"/>
        <esri:GraphicsLayer id="inputsLayer"/>
    </esri:Map>

</s:BorderContainer>
```

Do you have any advice?

Regards

Comment: Have you used firebug or fiddler to make sure all the parameters being passed in are correct?

Comment: @Jamie In FireBug parameters are :
`f json
returnBarriers false
returnDirections false
returnPolygonBarriers false
returnPolylineBarriers false
returnRoutes true
returnStops false
stops {"features":[{"geometry":{"x":655563.9391567005,"spatialReference":{"wkid":2154},"y":6861469.492592832}},{"geometry":{"x":655344.5428990924,"spatialReference":{"wkid":2154},"y":6861367.980891551}}],"doNotLocateOnRestrictedElements":false,"type":"features"}`
So I suppose yes. The parameters sent to the server are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. 
In the object Routetask:

```
<esri:RouteTask id="routeTask" concurrency="last" fault="faultHandler(event)"
                    requestTimeout="30" showBusyCursor="true"
                    solveComplete="solveCompleteHandler(event)"
                    url="http://serverIP:8399/arcgis/rest/services/na_service/MapServer/Route"/>
```

In the url attribute, there is a mistake. Instead of /MapServer there should be /NAServer like this:

```
url="http://serverIP:8399/arcgis/rest/services/na_service/NAServer/Route"
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: Ok thanks for the comment. I'm the author of the question and I have answered it. I have provided a more detailed answer. I agree with you, the previous answer wasn't clear.